# Using java regex read a text file to match multiple patterns

Tags: java, regex

Code that i tried:

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.regex.*;
public class All {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String input = "IT&&faculty.*";
        try {
            FileInputStream fstream = new FileInputStream("uu.txt");
            DataInputStream in = new DataInputStream(fstream);
            BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(in));
            String strLine;
            while ((strLine = br.readLine()) != null) {
                if (Pattern.matches(input, strLine)) {
                    Pattern p = Pattern.compile("'(.*?)'");
                    Matcher m = p.matcher(strLine);
                    while (m.find()) {
                        String b = m.group(1);
                        String c = b.toString() + ".*";
                        System.out.println(b);

                        if (Pattern.matches(c, strLine)) {
                            Pattern pat = Pattern.compile("<(.*?)>");
                            Matcher mat = pat.matcher(strLine);
                            while (mat.find()) {
                                System.out.println(m.group(1));

                            }
                        } else {
                            System.out.println("Not found");
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.err.println("Error: " + e.getMessage());
        }
    }
}
```

The contents of my text file are:
\ indicates it is a newline

Input file:

```
IT&&faculty('Mousum handique'|'Abhijit biswas'|'Arnab paul'|'Bhagaban swain')
 Mousum handique(designation|address|phone number|'IT Assistant          professor'|<AUS staff quaters>|#5566778899#)
 Abhijit biswas(designation|address|phone number|'IT Assistant professor'|<AUW staff quaters>|#5566778891#)
Arnab paul(designation|address|phone number|'IT Assistant professor'|<AUE staff quaters>|#5566778890#)
Bhagaban swain(designation|address|phone number|'IT Assistant professor'|<AUW staff quarters>|#5566778892#)
```

it gives result -

```
Mousum handique
Not found
Abhijit Biswas
Not found 
Arnab Paul
Not found
Bhagaban swain
Not found
```

whereas the results i want is:

```
Mousum handique
AUS staff quaters
Abhijit Biswas
AUW staff quaters
Arnab Paul
AUE staff quaters
Bhagaban swain
AUW staff quaters
```

That is i want after 1st match when it gets Mousum handique from the file it should again search the file and where it gets line like Mousum handique it should print whatever within <> for that corresponding line. Please refer data of my text file to understand my question. Sorry if my question seems stupid but i m trying it a lot!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You don't need to use `string.matches` method just use `Patttern` and Matcher classes to extract the name which was at the start of the line and also the contents between `<>` on the same line itself.

```
String s =  "IT&&faculty('Mousum handique'|'Abhijit biswas'|'Arnab paul'|'Bhagaban swain')\n" + 
        " Mousum handique(designation|address|phone number|'IT Assistant           professor'|<AUS staff quaters>|#5566778899#)\n" + 
        " Abhijit biswas(designation|address|phone number|'IT Assistant professor'|<AUW staff quaters>|#5566778891#)\n" + 
        "Arnab paul(designation|address|phone number|'IT Assistant professor'|<AUE staff quaters>|#5566778890#)\n" + 
        "Bhagaban swain(designation|address|phone number|'IT Assistant professor'|<AUW staff quarters>|#5566778892#)";
Matcher m = Pattern.compile("(?m)^\\s*([^\\(]+)\\([^\\)]*\\|<([^>]*)>[^\\)]*\\)").matcher(s);
while(m.find())
{
    System.out.println(m.group(1));
    System.out.println(m.group(2));
}
```

**Output:**

```
Mousum handique
AUS staff quaters
Abhijit biswas
AUW staff quaters
Arnab paul
AUE staff quaters
Bhagaban swain
AUW staff quarters
```

[DEMO](https://regex101.com/r/nG2xO7/1)

**Update:**

Use this regex to get also the id number.

```
String s =  "IT&&faculty('Mousum handique'|'Abhijit biswas'|'Arnab 
paul'|'Bhagaban swain')\n" + 
                " Mousum handique(designation|address|phone number|'IT Assistant           professor'|<AUS staff quaters>|#5566778899#)\n" + 
                " Abhijit biswas(designation|address|phone number|'IT Assistant professor'|<AUW staff quaters>|#5566778891#)\n" + 
                "Arnab paul(designation|address|phone number|'IT Assistant professor'|<AUE staff quaters>|#5566778890#)\n" + 
                "Bhagaban swain(designation|address|phone number|'IT Assistant professor'|<AUW staff quarters>|#5566778892#)";
        Matcher m = Pattern.compile("(?m)^\\s*([^\\(]+)\\([^\\)]*\\|<([^>]*)>[^\\)]*\\|#([^#]*)#[^\\)]*\\)").matcher(s);
        while(m.find())
        {
            System.out.println(m.group(1));
            System.out.println(m.group(2));
            System.out.println(m.group(3));
        }
```

**Output:**

```
Mousum handique
AUS staff quaters
5566778899
Abhijit biswas
AUW staff quaters
5566778891
Arnab paul
AUE staff quaters
5566778890
Bhagaban swain
AUW staff quarters
5566778892
```

Comment: Thans for helping but i cant take the data as a string i HAVE to take it in a text file and retrieve data from there only using regex . I have just given an instance that i require answer whatever within <..> after matching the corresponding name but sometimes after matching the name i may also need the one within #..#. Sorry, but plz help how to do using text file only

Comment: Problem is i cant strore the data of String s like that in a string i am to use a text file read it and then extract the data in first match if it finds name then in next match for that corresponding name it has to print <...> or #..# from the text file only. Plz help

Comment: you could apply the same regex on the text file itself. Just read the whole file and stored it in a variable. And then apply the above regex on that variable.

Comment: Is it not possible that way - that it first reads text file finds IT&&faculty(...) line after that for each name it searches match in the text file if it finds then for that corresponding line it prints whatever within <....> or  #...#

Comment: Is it not possible that way - that it first reads text file finds IT&&faculty(...) line after that for each name it searches match in the text file if it finds then for that corresponding line it prints whatever within <....> or  #...#

Comment: so you mean that the input is like this https://regex101.com/r/nG2xO7/4 and you want to fetch only the names which are next to the faculty, am i correct?

Comment: Exactly ,Actually that Pattern.compile(...) helped but it gives results for all the names present in the text file but i want it to work only for names present in the line IT&&faculty(...) so what to do ?

Comment: How about this https://regex101.com/r/nG2xO7/5 ? Don't be afraid , just use this regex in `Pattern.Compile` with the backslash escaped one more time.

Comment: No error but it results nothing -totally blank, should i put double backslash in \n also in the regex pattern ?

Comment: `Matcher m = Pattern.compile("(?m)(?:^IT&&faculty\\([^)\\n]*\\)|(?<!^)\\G)\\s*([^\\(\\n]+)\\([^\\)\\n]*\\|<([^>]*)>[^\\)\\n]*\\|#([^#\\n]*)#[^\\)\\n]*\\)").matcher(s);`

Comment: Runtime error- Dangling metacharacters near '?' near index 64 ; then the regex pattern is printed whatever within Pattern.compile("...")

Comment: @SoumyasreeBiswas please see the above ideone link.

Comment: In ideone in the string s at the end what is "fiuiu gdfsfs dgdgf grdr" and why the values are stored twice like mousum handique1 , abhijit biswas1 ?

Comment: in-order to differentiate the names.

Comment: So i need to store double values in my text file is it ? And after every answer 1 is coming ?

Comment: SInce you're new to StackOverflow, i suggest you to read [this](http://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer)

Comment: Please help me a little more if i put the above program in a servlet the answer is printed for only one value the while loop does not seem to work so where should i put the requestdispatcher line (at the end of while or where ?)  so that while loop works

Comment: @SoumyasreeBiswas ask this as a new question.

Comment: Hi, Could any one of you help me? I have a similar code which we have been using to match a yearly published document. But it doesn't work anymore for this year doc, for escaped characters. ex: I'm trying to match `my text//*` with doc content, it outputs no matches. * (has been escaped). I can get it work for all the other text without escaped characters. But when ever it finds any one of these `<([{\^-=$!|]})?*+.>` it couldn't get a match. But with almost 100% similar text from last year worked with this code. Help much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

One bug is here:

```
while (mat.find()) {
    System.out.println(m.group(1)); // <-- you should use mat - not m!!!
}
```

Second bug is here:

```
if (Pattern.matches(c, strLine)) {
```

This `if` is never entered since the String `c` is the previous match + "`.*`". Remove this if condition and it'll work.

Fixed code:

```
    ...
    Pattern p = Pattern.compile("'(.*?)'");
    Matcher m = p.matcher(strLine);
    while (m.find()) {
        String b = m.group(1);
        System.out.println(b);            
        Pattern pat = Pattern.compile("<(.*?)>");
        Matcher mat = pat.matcher(strLine);
        while (mat.find()) {
            System.out.println(mat.group(1));

        }            
    }
    ...
```

Running this code with the input:

```
"Abhijit biswas(designation|address|phone number|'IT Assistant professor'|<AUW staff quaters>|#5566778891#)
```

outputs:

```
IT Assistant professor
AUW staff quaters
```

Comment: This only resulted the names and did not give whatever within < > for each corresponding names

Comment: @SoumyasreeBiswas the example I was running with was: ""Abhijit biswas(designation|address|phone number|'IT Assistant professor'|<AUW staff quaters>|#5566778891#)". See the lasted section I just added to the answer.